Why is another function not passable as an argument in a test function without fixtures?
I am learning python and wrote a program to understand about testing code.
Code 1:
import pytest

class Employee:
    """Represent an employee"""

    def __init__(self, f_name, l_name, salary):
        self.f_name = f_name.title()
        self.l_name = l_name.title()
        self.salary = salary
    
    def give_raise(self, amount = 5000):
        """Give the employee a raise"""
        self.amount = amount
        self.r_salary = self.salary + self.amount



@pytest.fixture
def make_employee():
    """Creates an instance of an employee"""
    employee = Employee('wolfgang', 'mozart', 1_00_000_000)
    return employee

def test_give_default_raise(make_employee):
    """Test that a default raise works properly"""
    make_employee.give_raise()
    assert make_employee.r_salary == (make_employee.salary + make_employee.amount)


def test_give_custom_raise(make_employee):
    """Test that a custom raise works properly"""
    make_employee.give_raise(amount= 10_000)
    assert make_employee.r_salary == (make_employee.salary + make_employee.amount)

Code 2:
class Employee:
    """Represent an employee"""

    def __init__(self, f_name, l_name, salary):
        self.f_name = f_name.title()
        self.l_name = l_name.title()
        self.salary = salary
    
    def give_raise(self, amount = 5000):
        """Give the employee a raise"""
        self.amount = amount
        self.r_salary = self.salary + self.amount



def make_employee():
    """Creates an instance of an employee"""
    employee = Employee('wolfgang', 'mozart', 1_00_000_000)
    return employee

def test_give_default_raise(func = make_employee):
    """Test that a default raise works properly"""
    make_employee.give_raise()
    assert make_employee.r_salary == (make_employee.salary + make_employee.amount)


def test_give_custom_raise(func = make_employee):
    """Test that a custom raise works properly"""
    make_employee.give_raise(amount= 10_000)
    assert make_employee.r_salary == (make_employee.salary + make_employee.amount)

Question 1: Why does Code 2 fail the pytest? What am I doing wrong?
My purpose for writing Code 2 was that I was curious about an alternative way to pass a function as an argument in the definition of a test function without using fixtures. So with that in mind -
Question 2: What modifications do I need to do to fulfill the above purpose?

make_employee.give_raise() make_employee() is a function.  It doesn't have a .give_raise() attribute...

Question 1: Why does Code 2 fail the pytest? We don't know, because you did not  share the failure messages...

Even if that did work, shouldn’t you be testing func.give_raise(), or possibly func().give_raise()? Not quite sure what the intent was.

def test_give_default_raise(func = make_employee) What is the purpose of having func as a parameter, when you never use it?

@JohnGordon the first comment is a little unclear because make_employee.give_raise() works as expected in the first example. This is because pytest looks for arguments that match fixture names, calls the functions, and replaces the argument with the return value before running the test. However swapping it out func = make_employee breaks this. And as you say in the last comment, it's not clear what the objective is for doing this.

If you want the second version to work, you could save the instance returned from the function employee = func() and then use that for the rest of the test: employee.give_raise() assert employee.r_salary == (employee.salary + employee.amount) etc...
